# Quartz.net version 2.3.3 - setting up AdoJobStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I am using an `ASP.Net` website as a sort of back-end control panel, and I want to set it up so that when the user adds something to my database, it will create/schedule a job to send out a reminder to everybody on some date.

I have the job and trigger parts down and working, however I want to set it up to use `AdoJobStore` so that these jobs won't be lost (in case there is an instance where the reminder doesn't have to be sent out for a whole month or two).

I've tried using their official tutorial, some relevant posts here, and other guides I've found through google, but I can't figure out how to set this up at all. Most provide code that needs to be added to some kind of configuration file, but I can't seem to find any - I have seen them saying to edit `quartz.config`, `web.config`, or `quartz.properties`. I can only find the  `web.config` in `ASP.net` my project, but I can't seem to get any of the examples working inside this file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an ADOJobStore in your app.config/web.config and then some quartz.config.  I call mine QuartzDataStoreSettingsDatabase.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

</configSections>


<quartz configSource="QuartzDataStoreSettingsDatabase.config" />
```

Then the file for quartz specific stuff

QuartzDataStoreSettingsDatabase.config

```
<quartz>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ExampleDefaultQuartzSchedulerFromConfigFileSqlServer"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="instance_one"/>
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10"/>
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal"/>

<!-- 
org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime
Is the amount of time in milliseconds that the scheduler will wait before re-queries for available triggers when the scheduler is otherwise idle. Normally you should not have to 'tune' this parameter, unless you're using XA transactions, and are having problems with delayed firings of triggers that should fire immediately.
It defaults to every 30 seconds until it finds a trigger. Once it finds any triggers, it gets the time of the next trigger to fire and stops checking until then, unless a trigger changes.   -->
<add key="quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime" value ="5000"/>

<!-- Misfire : see http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html  -->
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="false"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"/>


<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="MySqlServerFullVersion"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="false"/>

<add key="quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.connectionString" value="SuperSecret!!"/>
<add key="quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.provider" value="SqlServer-20"/>
</quartz>
```

See my answer here:

[Unable to save anything to the Quartz.net ado store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955025/unable-to-save-anything-to-the-quartz-net-ado-store)

Then when an "event" happens in your website world.......you need to schedule a job programatically.

```
            NameValueCollection config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz");

            ShowConfiguration(config, logger);

            ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);

            IScheduler sched = factory.GetScheduler();


/* the below code has to be tweaked for YOUR Job */
        IJobDetail textFilePoppingJobJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<TextFilePoppingNonConcurrentJob>()
            .WithIdentity("textFilePoppingJobJobDetail001", "groupName007")
                            .UsingJobData("JobDetailParameter001", "Abcd1234")
            .Build();


        ITrigger textFilePoppingJobJobDetailTrigger001 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("textFilePoppingJobJobDetailTrigger001", "groupName007")
          .UsingJobData("TriggerParameter001", "Bcde2345")
          .UsingJobData("TempDirectorySubFolderName", "MyTempDirectorySubFolderName")
          .UsingJobData("DestinationFullFolderName", @"C:\SomeFolder")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
              .RepeatForever()
            /* .WithRepeatCount(1) */
              )
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(textFilePoppingJobJobDetail, textFilePoppingJobJobDetailTrigger001);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this out (wish I saw this sooner). I just want to confirm first that this works with Web Applications? Right now, the only issue I'm having is that over time the Web Application dies or something, so the job I have set to run once a week also dies and doesn't run. I tried making a job that fires every 10 minutes which calls a WebRequest to a random page, hoping it would keep the Web App alive so the jobs can persist over time, but it doesn't seem to be working.